# Hibernate : Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) , but mysql work fine

Tags: java, hibernate

I spend many days to try find problem so plz help me.

I have problem with hibernate with connection to database **always** have Exception  Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) even if i have user xx not root.

My hibernate.cfg.xml is:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">wojtek</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">xx</property>
  <mapping resource="program/Members.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I see that access denied is for root but in my hibenrate.cfg.xml is wojtek so here must be main problem.

BTW I could normal connect to database form line command as root or wojtek , aplication using jdbc too could connect but only with Hibernate i have access denied with wrong user.

Comment: Try either using 127.0.0.1 in your JDBC URL, or making sure that you have MySQL privileges granted for root@localhost (not just root@127.0.0.1). (Or wojtek@localhost or whatever user, root was an example). If that doesn't work try also granting privileges to username@% (% = any host).

Comment: Make sure your MySQL service is running..

Comment: MYSQL is fine, runing. WHen i change localhost as 127 its still not working i try this many days before and event if i change ip as other not localhost and username i will always have this same Exception Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 0):

One point to consider is that if your specify localhost when connecting to mysql, then mysql will use a `Unix Socket` not `TCP/IP`.  In order to ensure that mysql is is using `TCP/IP`, same as `Hibernate` ensure that when testing with mysql you specify --host.  The permissions for "Unix Socket" and "TCP/IP" are different.

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html

Comment: BTW I have this problem on windows xp and windows 7. I think in my aplication Hibernate dont take configuration form hibernate.cfg.xml. I will try and check this URL.

Comment: I read this url few times and dont find answer. True they write about TCP but in comandline this work fine so this cant be probelm with mysql or system , only with hibernate. I use Netbeans what have included Hibernate and dont know where is config file for Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and tried for hours to find the solution. Finally, I was able to solve the issue by updating the mysql-connector version. Try the latest connector version (5.1.29) and let me know if his works for you. This might help if you have updated your MySQL server version.

Answer (score 0):

Thx all for answer.

I think version jdk and version of netbeans had conflict thats why it doesnt work on my windows 7,xp,debian(on all this OS i used Netbeans 7.4 and jdk 7u51)

BTW : I installed Linux Mint and installed OpenJDK version 7u51 + netbeans 8 and all work fine.